# java: secondary call up of function causing missed data

Tags: java, function, return, logic

```
public double firstPastAsk(int rowIn)    
{
       ...

       System.out.println(trajectory(rowIn) + " " + primary(rowIn) + " " + finalAction(rowIn));

       return pastPrice;
}

String action = " ";    
public String finalAction(int rowIn)
{   
    action = "[" + primary(rowIn) + "]";
    return action ;
}

boolean buyFlag = false;
public String primary(int rowIn)
{
    String Request = "initial";

    if(trajectory(rowIn) == "BUY")
    {
        if(buyFlag == false)
        {
            buyFlag = true;
            Request = "REQUEST BUY";
        }   
    }   

    if(trajectory(rowIn) == "SELL")
    {       
        buyFlag = false;
        Request = "REQUEST SELL";
    }       
    return Request;
}
```

Results of println:

```
    TRAJECTORY:                PRIMARY:     FINAL ACTION:

    WAITING ON SUFFICIENT DATA initial      [initial]
    (BUY)                      REQUEST BUY  [initial]
                               initial      [initial]
    (SELL)                     REQUEST SELL [REQUEST SELL]
                               initial      [initial]
    (BUY)                      REQUEST BUY  [initial]
    (SELL)                     REQUEST SELL [REQUEST SELL]
    (BUY)                      REQUEST BUY  [initial]
```

With the above code, when "finalAction" is called up, which subsequently calls up "primary", it receives the return value of "REQUEST SELL" and "initial" but never the value of "REQUEST BUY". I'm having trouble understanding why "finalAction" is always receiving "initial" instead of "REQUEST BUY" yet "REQUEST SELL" is being received.

I appreciate any help in understanding this problem and sorry if there are any formatting or clarity issues present, I will fix them up next time I post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time `firstPastAsk` is called, `primary` is called twice. And because `buyFlag` is a global state. When `finalAction` calls `primary`, `buyFlag` state is already changed by the previous `primary`.

To fix this issue, you can pass the result of first call of `primary` to `finalAction` so `primary` is only called once.

```
public double firstPastAsk(int rowIn)    
{
   ...
   String primaryResult = primary(rowIn);
   System.out.println(trajectory(rowIn) + " " + primaryResult + " " + finalAction(primaryResult));

   return pastPrice;
}

public String finalAction(String primaryResult)
{   
    action = "[" + primaryResult + "]";
    return action ;
}
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you for looking through the logic, I understand the error now!